# Combine elements that has same pattern in a list to strings

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that could vary in pattern.

```
lst = ['ban-eur.kd', 'ban-eur.sd', 'ban-eur.td' ]
```

When converted this should become `ban-eur<kd,sd,td>`.

It should combine elements that are next only if they can be combined. (only if it matches the pattern `ban-eur`)

```
lst = ['ban-eur.kd', 'kd', 'ban-eur.sd', 'ban-eur.td' ]
```

This should result in `'ban-eur.kd_kd_ban-eur<sd,td>'.`

If it doesn't have any element that could be combined then it should all be just joined with a `_`

How can I do this, without missing the first element in the array/duplicate with in the string.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, re
lst = ['ban-eur.kd', 'ban-eur.sd', 'ban-eur.td' ]
def group_result(d:list) -> list:
   if len(d) == 1:
     return d[0]
   new_result = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x.split('.')[0]), key=lambda x:x.split('.')[0])]
   return '_'.join('{}<{}>'.format(a, ','.join(i.split('.')[-1] for i in b)) for a, b in new_result)

new_data = '_'.join(group_result(list(b)) if a else '_'.join(list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x:'.' in x))
```

Output:

```
'ban-eur<kd,sd,td>'
```

When running on `['ban-eur.kd', 'kd', 'ban-eur.sd', 'ban-eur.td']`:

```
'ban-eur.kd_kd_ban-eur<sd,td>'
```

Comment: @Ajax1234, I didn't understand your method (d:list) -> list. Could you explain please.

Comment: I think it works with version 3 and above .but not in 2.7.@Ajax1234

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
pre = ''
result = []
endings = []
for item in lst:
    if item.split('.')[0] == pre:
        endings.append(item.split('.')[1])
    else:
        if endings:
            result.append(pre+'<'+','.join(endings)+'>')
        else:
            result.append(item)
        pre = item.split('.')[0]
        endings = []
print('_'.join(result))
```

Comment: your indentation is a bit off

Answer (score 0):

```
 matches = []
 resulting_string
 for item in lst:
     if item.startsWith('ban-eur'):
         matches.append(item)
     elif not item.startsWith('ban-eur') and len(matches) >= 1:
         if len(matches) == 1:
            resulting_string += item
         else:
            resulting_string += 'ban-eur.<'
            for s in matches:
                resulting_string += s + ', '
            resulting_string += '>'
            matches = []
     resulting_string += '_' + item + '_'
```